# VueJS get request every 20 minutes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I fetch data from a get request to display coin name information. I want this to update every 20 minutes.
For test-drive, I keep it 500 milliseconds. It always and always fetch data and add current list, so I am getting `Duplicate keys detected: 'BUSDRON'. This may cause an update error` this error and also my app is freezing.

How can I getting data from above link request every 20 minute, without dublicating values?
Also it
My fetch codes is here

```
 methods: {
    async fetchApi() {
      const response = await fetch(
        'https://api2.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr'
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      await data.forEach(element => {
        this.chartData.symbols = [...this.chartData.symbols, element.symbol];
        this.chartData.price = [...this.chartData.price, +element.lastPrice];
      });
    },
}



 data: () => ({
        timer: '',
    )}


async created() {
    this.loaded = false;

    try {
      this.timer = setInterval(this.fetchApi, 500);

      this.loaded = true;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  },
```

Comment: If you have an array that you iterate on, there is a `:key` on it. If you push an identical object to the array, it will have the same `key` hence the duplicate. Either don't push exactly the same object there if already present or create a unique `key`.

Comment: Also, `forEach` is sync, no need to have an `await` in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

Before your forEach loop, reset the arrays for symbols and price to an empty array, then push the new values to them inside of the forEach loop.

```
const response = await fetch(
    'https://api2.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr'
  );
const data = await response.json();
const symbols = [];
const price = [];

data.forEach(element => {
  symbols.push(element.symbol);
  price.push(element.lastPrice);
});

this.chartData.symbols = symbols;
this.chartData.price = price;
```

Comment: Wipe the whole array every time? Quite extreme solution.

Comment: Not extreme at all, just replacing the old data with the new.

Comment: I re-phrase it: not really scalable. No point in having an array if you only keep a single element in the state. Anyway, too naive overall to be a good enough solution IMO.

Comment: not scalable in what way? Also, it's not keeping a single element in the array, if you look at the endpoint from the question, it has 2136 objects. So this would replace the old arrays of 2136 items with the latest versions of those 2136 items with no need to check for duplicates.

Comment: Did you already try to put 2k elements in an array on the client-side? Try it and you'll understand why this is not scalable. Hint: blocking the main thread and freezing the page. Doing that every X minutes? Nope, not scalable or clean.

Comment: It's fine, it could handle 10 times that in a few milliseconds. As they are using Vue, it probably would be better to create a new array, push to that and then replace the reactive version with the new array so will update the answer.

Comment: So, your hardware is able to load https://api2.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr in a few milliseconds? Impressive if true but most people are not using such hardware (especially on mobile devices).

Comment: What would you do to replace the old data with the new then? Anything else I can think of, like checking for only objects that have changed, checking for duplicates etc is going to take longer than just replacing all of it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy) from lodash to remove duplicates.

Not sure the uniqueness would be based on the latest data. For safety, we reverse the array. After filtering the unique date, we reverse the array again in the order it should be.

```js
methods: {
    async fetchApi() {
      const response = await fetch(
        'https://api2.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr'
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      this.chartData = _.uniqBy([...this.data, data].reverse(), 'symbols').reverse()
    }
}
```

Comment: `uniqBy` was a good start, not sure why you want to double reverse it tho.

Comment: The initial reverse is because the retainers of the data would be from top to down. If this is the case, we would have stale data as the newly appended data to the array might be a victim of the filter.

The second reverse is because we are sure our data has been filtered with high precision but new data are now at the top of the array. So reversing it makes the old data stay at the top and new data at the bottom of the array.